# Django ORM "get" translation to SQL

Tags: django, django-models

For a Queryset in Django, we can call its method .query to get the raw sql.

for example,

```
queryset = AModel.objects.all()
print queryset.query
```

the output could be: SELECT "id", ... FROM "amodel"

But for retrieving a object by "get", say,

```
item = AModel.objects.get(id = 100)
```

how to get the equivalent raw sql? Notice: the item might be None.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `item = AModel.objects.get(id = 100)` equals to

```
items = AModel.objects.filter(id = 100)
if len(items) == 1:
    return items[0]
else:
    raise exception
```

Thus the executed query equals to `AModel.objects.filter(id = 100)`

Also, you could check the latest item of `connection.queries`

```
from django.db import connection # use connections for non-default dbs
print connection.queries[-1]
```

And, as FoxMaSk said, install `django-debug-toolbar` and enjoy it in your browser.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same SQL, just with a `WHERE id=100` clause tacked to the end.

However, FWIW, If a `filter` is specific enough to only return one result, it's the same SQL as `get` would produce, the only difference is on the Python side at that point, e.g.

```
AModel.objects.get(id=100)
```

is the same as:

```
AModel.objects.filter(id=100).get()
```

So, you can simply query `AModel.objects.filter(id=100)` and then use `queryset.query` with that.

Answer (score 2):

if it's just for debugging purpose you can use "the django debug bar" which can be installed by

```
pip install django-debug-toolbar
```